# Modifying this code to take only one parameter (length of character combination)?

Tags: java, string, recursion

I'm trying to modify the java code in answer 2 in  [here][Generating character combination in a string doesn't work entirely, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586589/generating-character-combination-in-a-string-doesnt-work-entirely-why) to have one method that does the entire job and take only one parameter, the number of characters in the combinations (i.e. called in main as method(int)).

It's actually a homework, to write a recursive code that does the same as the code in the link above, i.e. print all character combinations of desired length but in this case from a fixed set of characters, A, C, G and T (e.g. if called method(2), it prints AA, AC, AG, AT, CA, CC...).

So far I've only got:

```
public static void printAllDNAs(int n) {
    String[] dna;
    dna = new String[4];
    dna[0] = "A";
    dna[1] = "C";
    dna[2] = "G";
    dna[3] = "T";

    String prfx = "";
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(prfx);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < dna.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(prfx + dna[i]);
            printAllDNAs(n - 1);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printAllDNAs(3);
}
}
```

Which obviously isn't right at all. I understand that I need to give prfx the value of each of the letters in the set in turn and append one or more characters from the set to it. Could someone give me a hint or two which way I should go with this? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
public static void printDNARecursive(ArrayList<String> dnaCombinations, String prefix, String[] dnaArray, int depth) {
    if (prefix.length() == depth || dnaArray.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dnaArray.length; i++) {
        String dna = dnaArray[i];
        if (dna == null) {
            continue;
        }
        dnaCombinations.add(prefix + dna);
        String[] copyOf = Arrays.copyOf(dnaArray, dnaArray.length);
        copyOf[i] = null;
        printDNARecursive(dnaCombinations, prefix + dna, copyOf, depth);
    }
}
```

How it work - this code use instead of printing DNA to screen it save them inside `dnaCombinations` variable. If your DNA achievie length of max depth (as `depth` variable) then it won't go further.

It's a little different from your because inside `dnaCombinations` you will have also `"A", "C", "G", "T"` but then you can print from `dnaCombinations` only string with length of your choice.

Here little example how it work:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] dna = new String[] { "A", "C", "G", "T"};
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    printDNARecursive(result, "", dna, 2);
    for (String d : result) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

And the results are: `A AC AG AT C CA CG CT G GA GC GT T TA TC TG`

Feel free to add any modification or use it just as a template

Comment: Many thanks! Alas, in this algorithms and data structures course we are not allowed to use additional ready-made classes such as ArrayList, unless specified. But I'll learn a lot from this so it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`String prfx` needs to be outside the function. Replacing it with a `char[]` also makes things a lot easier and faster. See solution below.

If you just want one function:

```
private static char arr[];
private static final char[] dna = "ACGT".toCharArray();
public static void printAllDNAs(int n)
{
   if (arr == null)
      arr = new char[n];
   if (n == 0)
   {
      System.out.println(String.valueOf(arr));
      return;
   }
   for (char c: dna)
   {
      arr[n-1] = c;
      printAllDNAs(n-1);
   }
   if (n == arr.length)
      arr = null;
}
```

If you don't mind multiple functions, this would probably be better (+ very slightly faster):

```
public static void printAllDNAs(int n)
{
  arr = new char[n];
  printAllDNAsInternal(n);
}

private static void printAllDNAsInternal(int n)
{
   if (n == 0)
   {
      System.out.println(String.valueOf(arr));
      return;
   }
   for (char c: dna)
   {
      arr[n-1] = c;
      printAllDNAs(n-1);
   }
}
```